# Thread states linux vs windows

Tags: windows, scheduling

Linux has: ready, blocked, running, terminated.

Windows has: Ready, Deferred ready, Standby, Running, Waiting, Terminated, Initialized.

Why does Windows have so many states? What advantage does this extra complexity give?

Comment: This is a question about Windows, not a question about science. There might be a scientific question behind it (why such states are useful) but that would require knowing how those states are used.

Comment: short answer...scheduling. Because windows has more states, it can perform more nuanced scheduling of threads based on their ability to execute at any given time. there is no point to giving a process in a waiting state time, just as there is no point to suspending a thread in an initialized state. This is an immensely complex topic, and there has been a lot of debate and argument about how linux performs thread scheduling (see the Con Kolivas controversy)   which may give you some context. the TLDR is stock linux is optimized for server loads and windows is for desktop responsiveness.

Comment: Thank you for your response @FrankThomas. I have been reading about the topic today and was in need of some guidance as to why they chose so many states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **Running** thread is the thread that is currently executing on a processor.  The **Running** thread is selected from the list of **Ready** threads for that processor, which are threads that are good to be swapped in to execute.  The **Standby** thread is the **Ready** thread that is *currently* selected to be swapped in to the **Running** state next on that processor.  However, this may change if a higher priority thread becomes ready before the change is made.

**Deferred Ready** is a global state that indicates the thread is ready to run on *any* processor.  This can be used for one CPU to schedule a high priority thread on another CPU, for example.

Threads that are not **Ready** to run are given state determined by the reason they cannot run:

- Threads are placed in the **Initialized** state whilst they are being created.
- Threads can be **Waiting** on some event, such as synchronization or I/O completion, or can be forced to wait if they access memory that is paged to disk, for example.  Once the event has been signalled, or the timeout has elapsed, the thread will be eligible to run again.
- Threads are placed in **Transition** state because their kernel stack has been paged out.  These threads will not be ready to run until their kernel stack is available again.
- Threads that have exited are placed in **Terminated** state until the system has cleaned up.

[image]

It should be noted that thread states are completely separate from scheduling priorities, which determine the order in which threads are selected to run.

Comment: Where does the image come from? I think we should have a citation here...